# Migrate Users from one ADB2C to another across 2 different subscription

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We want to migrate Users from one ADB2C to another across 2 different subscriptions. There is no option to import/export – what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this.

You have to [roll your own](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#user-migration).